# Accessing a facebook Iframe by jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

Lots of similar problems have been asked about accessing a iframe by javascript maybe this will be one of them. But as I looked into answers about this issue, I understand I can not access a iframe if it is in a different domain like facebook. What I wanted is using facebook send/like system and gathering facebookids' by looking at the iframe of the facebook that opened in my website.

The interesting point for me is I can see the ids and all the contents of html by inspecting elements of the iframe but when I tried to access elements by jquery it says "it is forbidden" . I am just trying to parse html so how does facebook understand that and ignore the operation ?

all the iframe scenarios' are ignoring these type of accesses and how to do that ?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: parent frames have no access to foreign domains see [same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy)

Comment: You may have to use a facebook API to get this information.

Answer (score 1):

You can see it via inspect element tool, only because browser allows it specificaly for that tool (imagine it as there is an agreement between firefox and firebug, chrome and its validation tool and so one).

On the other hand it is impossible to access it directly through javacript, so you will not be able to access the html of iframe.